# How is the expression $\frac{\|\rho^{T_B}\|-1}{2}$ obtained from the definition of negativity?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, density-matrix, partial-transpose, entanglement-negativity

In quantum information theory, negativity is defined as summation of the absolute values of negative eigenvalues of the partial transposed density matrix. The expression of negativity is given as
$$
\mathcal{N}\left(\rho_{AB}\right)=\frac{|| \rho_{AB}^{T_B} || -1}{2}.
$$
However, I am unable to understand how do we arrive at this expression from the definition. Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly
$$
\mathrm{Tr}[\rho_{AB}^{T_B}] = 1
$$
as the transpose map is trace-preserving. As the trace of $\rho_{AB}^{T_B}$ is equal to the sum of its eigenvalues we have
$$
\sum_i \lambda_i = 1
$$
where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $\rho_{AB}^{T_B}$. For a normal matrix $X$ we also have that $\|X\|_1 = \sum_{i} |\lambda_i|$, thus we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|\rho_{AB}^{T_B}\|_1 - 1 &= \sum_i |\lambda_i| - \sum_i \lambda_i \\
&= \sum_{i: \lambda_i \geq 0} \lambda_i + \sum_{i : \lambda_i < 0}(-\lambda_i) - \sum_i \lambda_i \\
&=  - 2 \sum_{i:\lambda_i < 0} \lambda_i
\end{aligned}
$$
where on the second line we split the sum of $|\lambda_i|$ into a sum of the nonnegative eigenvalues and a sum of the negative eigenvalues. Dividing through by $2$ we see we are left with just the total absolute sum of the negative eigenvalues.

Comment: I have a doubt. We know that transpose map preserves eigenvalues and hence trace. But partial transpose does not always preserve eigenvalues (since a density matrix has all positive eigenvalues but its partial transpose may not). So how can we say that partial transpose will always preserve trace?

Comment: If $\mathcal{E}$ is a trace-preserving map and $\mathcal{F}$ is a trace-preserving map then $\mathcal{E}\otimes \mathcal{F}$ is a trace-preserving map. To see this note we can write any bipartite matrix $M$ in the form $M = \sum_k X_k \otimes Y_k$ and so
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{Tr}[(\mathcal{E}\otimes \mathcal{F})(M)] &= \sum_k \mathrm{Tr}[\mathcal{E}(X_k) \otimes \mathcal{F}(Y_k)]\\ &= \sum_k \mathrm{Tr}[\mathcal{E}(X_k)] \mathrm{Tr}[\mathcal{F}(Y_k)] \\ &= \sum_k \mathrm{Tr}[X_k] \mathrm{Tr}[Y_k] \\ &= \mathrm{Tr}[M]
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Okay, understood. Thank you!